# Redefine \item to get an HTML list

Tags: itemize, html

I would like to add a feature to a documentclass that converts the output to HTML in a low-tech solution. I already managed to convert text decorations (bold, italic, ...) and math environments to my liking, but I failed to achieve the same for lists. What I would like to have is that

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Number One
\item Number Two
\end{itemize}
```

yields

```
<ul>
<li>Number One</li>
<li>Number Two</li>
</ul>
```

I actually achieved the outer part to get the enclosing `<ul>` tags, but I failed to redefine `\item` appropriately because I don't fully get the implementation with the lookahead. My question is thus: *how can I redefine `\item` to get the desired result?*

Comment: do you need the closing `</li>` seeing as they are optional in html? You could simply make \item make `<li>`

Comment: Thank you DavidCarlisle, both for the excellent answer and this hint, I actually didn't know they were optional in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\itemize{\par<ul>\let\zz\relax}
\def\enditemize{\zz</ul>}
\def\item{\zz\par\indent\indent<li>\def\zz{\ifhmode\unskip\fi</li>\par}}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Number One
\item Number Two
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```